# Which is correct: to 'throw hard' or 'throw fast'?

Tags: adverbs

Which is the correct adverb? Or can both be used?

If so, how should one decide which one to use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***Throw the ball hard*** means 'throw it with high velocity, using as much power as you can muster'.

***Throw the ball fast***, means 'be quick about picking it up and throwing it'.